# Is there a transmitter that will fire a YN600EX-RT II and a RF603C II?

Tags: flash, off-camera-flash, wireless-flash

The RF603C II is great because I can carry one in my pocket and it will trigger the corresponding one on the camera.

Also the RF603C II (as transmitter) will trigger other flashes (with RF603C II as receiver) I have that take a sync wire.

But I also use YN600EX-RT II which has its own wireless technology to run with other YN600EX-RT II.

Is there a way to have either the master YN600EX-RT II or RF603C II on the camera trigger BOTH the dumb RF603C II receivers and the YN600EX-RT II slaves? And can I do that still with remote RC trigger somehow?

Comment: Do the flashes you use the RF603C II with have "dumb" S1 and S2 slave modes?

Answer (score 4):

Nope.

They use the same frequencies, as do most current wireless radio flash systems. But they use different protocols. In other words, they speak different languages.

The YN560/RF605/RF603 is one of two Yongnuo developed protocols. The other is the YN622 system. And while YN622 units made after the end of 2014 can *receive* YN560 commands, they can't send them.

The YN600EX-RT II clones the Canon RT protocol, as does the YN-ET-R3 II (and any of Yongnuo's other units with "RT" in the model name).

Answer (score 2):

Not as far as I know. The traditional way to get two incompatible triggering systems to work together is to stack one transmitter unit on top of another, but in this specific case the problem is that all the RT-compatible transmitters, the Canon ST-E3-RT, Yongnuo YN-E3-RT, Phottix Laso transmitter, and the Jinbei TR-Q7 do not have a hotshoe. And the RF-603II/RF-605II hotshoe is not full passthrough TTL.

To do what you want with a cabled RF-603II/605 but have it trigger with the YN600EX-RT, you'd have to use a (now discontinued) Yongnuo YN-E3-RX receiver instead of the RF60x unit, cabled to the flash.